# Angular 7/ ionic 4 Mutation Observer not finding DOM element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to scroll down to the bottom of the view when there is a new element inside the DOM and it is not being recognized.

```html
<ion-content #content>
  <ng-container *ngIf="messages$.length; else loading">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let message of messages$">
        <ion-col
          *ngIf="id === message.id"
          size="9"
          offset="3"
          class="message my-message"
          [ngStyle]="{ background: message.isUrgent ? 'var(--ion-color-danger)' : 'var(--ion-color-primary)' }"
        >
// hiding  more divs for brevity
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-content>
```

component.ts

```js
  private mutationObserver: MutationObserver;

  @ViewChild(IonContent) private content: IonContent;
  @ViewChild(IonCol, { read: ElementRef }) private chatList: ElementRef
//note, above I have tried, IonList/Row/Col/Grid

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[]): void => {
      console.log('here', mutations);
      this.content.scrollToBottom();
    });
    this.mutationObserver.observe(this.chatList.nativeElement, {
      childList: true,
    });
  }
```

I don't ever see the `here` in console

any help greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

as per this link https://www.joshmorony.com/shadow-dom-usage-in-ionic-web-components/
mutant observer needs to monitor shadowRoot rather than the element itself
try changing the code like below

```
 this.mutationObserver.observe(this.chatList.nativeElement.shadowRoot , {
      childList: true,
    });
```

Comment: I'm not the one that down voted, but if you do what you suggest you'll see the following error. `TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` So using the `nativeElement` is correct.

Comment: Shadowroots are so frustrating.  Or could try attaching to blah.shadowRoot.children[0] which is the scrollable element